# Displaying a parallel data in html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have very simple code:

```
 $resultTest = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventarioStat WHERE `localizacion` = 'Sagasta'  GROUP BY fecha") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 


    $rowTest = mysql_fetch_array( $resultTest );
    echo "<table border='1' padding='2' cellspacing='0' >";
     { foreach($rowTest['fecha'] as $key => $value) {



    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $rowTest['fecha'][$key] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .  $rowTest['idItem'][$key] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $rowTest['nombreItem'][$key] ."</td></tr>";






        mysql_query($query);
    }     

}


echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
```

What Im trying to get is to display all the data next to each other group by date using the html table, something like this:

```
Fecha                  Fecha                  Fecha
idItem nombre cantidad idItem nombre cantidad idItem nombre cantidad etc...
```

My code doesnt seems to be working. Can you push me in the right direction? 
Thank you

Comment: What is the output currently displayed.Can you show an image of your output?

Comment: `mysql_fetch` functions return a **SINGLE** row of data from your query. You're treating it as if it returns ALL of the data.

Comment: Is there anyway to combine two query and run them parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this?

```
 $resultTest = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventarioStat WHERE `localizacion` = 'Sagasta'  GROUP BY fecha") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 


    echo "<table border='1' padding='2' cellspacing='0'>";
    echo "<tr>";
     {

   while ($rowTest = mysql_fetch_array( $resultTest )) {
    echo "<td>";
    echo $rowTest['fecha'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $rowTest['idItem'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $rowTest['nombreItem'] ."</td></tr>";
    echo "</td>";
    }     

}

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I do get the results, but the inside the cell -I got displayed only one item as suppose all of them.

Comment: I've edit the code a bit by the way. But are you sure "SELECT * FROM inventarioStat WHERE `localizacion` = 'Sagasta'  GROUP BY fecha" returns more than one row? I mean if you apply it on phpMyAdmin, do you get more than one row as a result? :)

Comment: You are right. I tried it in myphpadmin and returns the same thing, although there is much more items for that date. ITs the query issue then? It seems to only display the first row.

Comment: Certainly. Check the rows, and try to build a proper query. Make sure that other entries don't have leading or trailing spaces that prevent them from appearing on this query!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `>` i your code:

```
echo "<table border='1' padding='2' cellspacing='0' ";
```

Change it to:

```
echo "<table border='1' padding='2' cellspacing='0'>";
```

Comment: Ashrafs answers seems to do the trick but its not displaying all the data for that date.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the `table`-tag: the `>` is missing.

It should be  `echo "<table border='1' padding='2' cellspacing='0'>";`

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of this:

```
mysql_query($query);
```

inside the foreach loop? The variable "$query" does not appear to be declared anywhere, if you haven't declared this it could be causing a problem.

Try this:

```
 $resultTest = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventarioStat WHERE `localizacion` = 'Sagasta'  GROUP BY fecha") 
or die(mysql_error()); 


$rowTest = mysql_fetch_array( $resultTest );
echo "<table border='1' padding='2' cellspacing='0' >";
 foreach($rowTest['fecha'] as $key => $value) 
   {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $rowTest['fecha'][$key] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" .  $rowTest['idItem'][$key] . "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $rowTest['nombreItem'][$key] ."</td></tr>";

}     


echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
```